# How to read following format in Sharepoint designer workflow?

Tags: 2013, workflow

```
Affected_x0020_Program: {
results: [2]
0:  {
__metadata: {
id: "2fbd598f-c7b5-4f01-baf8-7853aada5f0f"
type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
Title: "Vijay"
}-
1:  {
__metadata: {
id: "7d6d2d33-27c8-4d50-846a-bca923dfdb04"
type: "SP.Data.ProgramsListItem"
}-
Title: "Hole"
}-
-
}
```

How to read above JSON in Sharepoint designer workflow using HTTP web service ?

Answer (score 0):

For reading you should get the results in a dictionary variable using `Get Item from a Dictionary` action. This action contains three parameters:

1. Item by name or path – specifies the path where the item(s) resides
2. Dictionary – the dictionary variable to retrieve the item(s) from
3. Item – the variable to store the results in.

In the `Item by name or path` parameter you will enter `Affected_x0020_Program/results`. In the `dictionary` parameter you will select the jsonResponse variable. In the `item` parameter, you will create a new dictionary variable named `results`.

Next, we want to loop through the items returned from web service call.

Comment: I have try with Affected_x0020_Program/results but getting error that can not access as string.